# Query Ad-Hoc (Temporary) Views with ektorp

Tags: couchdb, ektorp

How do I fetch data using a temporary view with ektorp. I would like to pass the map javascript function to couchdb as a string and get the results. (This is definitely possible with CouchDB4J)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately CouchDB have well-documented API and you can do this using HttpURLConnection. That's not the easiest way, but that will work in any case

Comment: Little more explanation here http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Temporary_Views .  Note this is not performant.  Also view source in futon if you want to see temp views being sent.  http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/yourdb.html?kookaburra/_temp_view